# How to buy a million ripples?

Tags: ripple, trading

If someone wanted to buy up lots of ripples, say a million, how would they go about doing it?

Currently the exchanges don't seem to give good rates, and trading one-to-one with someone else would be inefficient. Is OpenCoin selling directly? At the current Bitstamp rate, it would cost $4444.44 to buy 1,000,000 XRP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now you can request a private sale at a good rate by emailing Bitstamp customer service or directly Nejc Kodrič  (nejc dot kodric at bitstamp.net)

Comment: Citation? Why would they offer a better rate outside the exchange?

Comment: The will offer a better rate because they want your money. Nejc Kodrič is the man to talk to. I have no idea what the rates are or whether that's a large enough amount for them to give you a discount.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Any comments on how much the next giveaway is going to be, and how it's going to be distributed?

Comment: Not yet, sorry.

Comment: Wow, did the OP ever make this purchase which would be worth in excess of $30 million today?